# How can I replace Key Value with value keys of a Map

Tags: java

I want to write a method which will take a map as parameter and replace the keys and values of that map by values and keys. I am trying to do it like this:

```
public class HashMapKeyValueInterchange{
       public static Map<String, String> getMyMap(ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> m){
           Map<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
           for(Entry<String, String> e:m.entrySet()){
               map2.put(e.getValue(), e.getKey());
           }
           return map2;
       }

       public static void main(String[] args) {
           ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> map1 = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, String>();
           map1.put("ajay", "btech");
           map1.put("manas", "mca");
           map1.put("ashu", "mba");
       }    
}
```

Using this method I can get a new map(map2) with exchanged key and values, but I want map1 to be exchanged

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Where is the code that is using the class HashMapKeyValueInterchange?

Comment: IMO what you have done looks good.. I dont think there is a better way!

Comment: You didnt call `getMyMap` method.

Answer (score 2):

It is availabe, no need to reinvent the wheel, if you use google collection library Guava then you can use [`BiMap<K,V>`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html).

> It is a map that preserves the uniqueness of its values as well as
>   that of its keys. This constraint enables bimaps to support an
>   "inverse view", which is another bimap containing the same entries as
>   this bimap but with reversed keys and values.

Implementation of `BiMap` are `EnumBiMap, EnumHashBiMap, [HashBiMap][2], ImmutableBiMap`

Comment: Seema to me like Guava reinvented the wheel here and the, see http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/BidiMap.html

Answer (score 0):

If the question is if the code works, the answer is yes.  Some comments:

1. If you want your code tested, you need to call `getMyMap` with map1 or other adequate parameter.
2. If you want to see any output, you need to write something like `System.out.println( getMyMap( map1 ) );`
3. I'd strongly recommend to use `Map` instead of `ConcurrentHashMap` as `getMyMap`'s 1st parameter type, so the function is more general an works with other maps.
4. To make your code even more general, make it:

   ```
   public static <K,V> void getMyMap(Map<V,K> output,Map<K,V> input) {
       for(Entry<K,V> e: input.entrySet() ) {
           output.put(e.getValue(), e.getKey());
       }
   }
   ```

   This will accept a bigger variety of `Map`'s and store the output in any type of `Map` is passed as the first parameter.  Example:

   ```
   getMyMap(new TreeMap<String,String>(),map1);
   getMyMap(new HashMap<String,String>(),map1);
   ```

A final point is that you don't specify a behavior when values are repeated.  The assumption above is that either this case does not occur or that any key in the input map is acceptable as value in the output one.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
public static ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> getMyMap(ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> m){
       ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> map2 = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, String>();
       for(Entry<String, String> e:m.entrySet()){
            map2.put(e.getValue(), e.getKey());
       }
       return map2;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> map1 = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, String>();
    map1.put("ajay", "btech");
    map1.put("manas", "mca");
    map1.put("ashu", "mba");
    map1 = getMyMap(map1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**BiMap is a good choice for this kind of operation**

> A BiMap is a Map that
>       allows you to view the "inverse" BiMap with inverse()
>       ensures that values are unique, making values() a Set

**`BiMap.put(key, value)` will throw an `IllegalArgumentException`** if you attempt to map a key to an already-present value. If you wish to delete any pre-existing entry with the specified value, use `BiMap.forcePut(key, value)` instead.

```
BiMap<String, Integer> userId = HashBiMap.create();
String userForId = userId.inverse().get(id);
```

Look [here](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#BiMap) for more information